# Obtaining a specific string from a line written in file

Tags: java, string

I have a file from which i read line by line and i have written a code for obtaining a certain portion of the string(from that line) which comes between two specific words eg

```
[abc] long time ago [cde]
```

Now i have written the following code for obtaining  the string long time ago

```
if (line.contains("[abc]") && line.contains("[cde]")) {
    int b = line.indexOf("abc");
    int cc = line.indexOf("cde");
    String tk = line.substring(b + 4, cc);
    System.out.println(tk);
}
```

This code works fine but now the problem is that.i come across the following line

```
[abc] long time ago [cde]    [abc] Everyday is a new day [cde]
```

Now, just give me an idea how to obtain these two strings... because they come on a same line and my code just considers the first one...

Comment: Will the file ever have overlapping tags? I.e. `[abc] long time ago     [abc] Everyday [cde]is a new day [cde]`

Comment: @ no , they are not overlapping..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (line.contains("[abc]") && line.contains("[cde]")) {
    int b = line.indexOf("abc");
    int cc = line.indexOf("cde");
    String tk = line.substring(b + 4, cc);
    System.out.println(tk);
    line = line.substring(cc + 4);
}
```

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL this gives an unending loop... it keeps repeating long time ago ... :(

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, this particular part works for me. http://ideone.com/XeZy6

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions [of this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as they will match every occurrence of a given String.